# Is a smooth function convex near a strict minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima

This is a self-answered question. I decided to ask it, since I find it natural, and the solution wasn't trivial for me. Of course, different answers are more than welcomed.

Let $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function. Suppose that $f$ is strictly  decreasing on $(-1,0]$, and is strictly increasing on $[0,1)$

> Is $f$ convex in some neighbourhood of zero?

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19473/104576), there is a counter-example when $0$ is not a strict minimum.

Comment: An explicit example: $f(x)=\exp(-1/|x|)(1+\sin^2\left(\frac1x\right))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to "go one step" further in the chain of derivatives, and to understand what properties do we need from $f'$, in order to get an example of a non-convex function with a strict minimum.

Let $g:[0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be a smooth function satisfying

1. $g(x) > g(0)=0$ for every $0< x < 1$
2. $g'$ obtains negative values at points which are arbitrarily close to $0$.
3. $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for every $k$.

Such functions [exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3675710/104576). Given such a function $g$, define $h:(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ by
$$ h(x)=
\begin{cases}
g(x),  & \text{ if  }\, x \ge 0\\
-g(-x), & \text{ if  }\, x \le 0
\end{cases}$$

Property $(3)$ of $g$ implies that $h$ is smooth. Note that $h>0$ on $(0,1)$ and $h<0$ on $(-1,0)$.

Finally, define $f(x)=\int_0^x h(t)dt$. Then 
$$ f''(x)=
\begin{cases}
g'(x),  & \text{ if  }\, x \ge 0\\
g'(-x), & \text{ if  }\, x \le 0
\end{cases}$$
obtains negative values arbitrarily close to $0$, by property $(2)$ of $g$.