# Is a non-differentiable function convex near a strict minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, maxima-minima

Let $f:(-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ be a **continuous** function, which is **not** differentiable at zero. Suppose that $f$ is strictly  decreasing on $(-1,0]$, and is strictly increasing on $[0,1)$.

Is $f$ convex in some neighbourhood of zero?

I know that if $f$ is smooth at zero, then it does not need to convex near zero. (One can construct examples using bump functions, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/19473/104576) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3677359/104576).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this functions fit to your conditions?
$$
f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}
$$

Comment: Yes, thanks! That was easier than I thought...

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out that the example in the first linked post is easily modified to produce a function that is non-differentiable at $0$, not convex at $0$, and $f(0)=0$ is a strict minimum (i.e. the smoothness was supposed to make it "harder" to prove):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2 + \max(0,x)^2\sin^2 \frac1x & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$$
The $x^2$ makes it so that the unique zero of $f$ is $x=0$, and $f>0$ otherwise. Its not convex to the right of $0$ because $f$ "jumps" between the $x^2$ curve and $2x^2$ curve infinitely often. That it is not differentiable at $0$ is more or less standard.

Answer (score 0):

An example similar to daw's is:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\arcsin(-2x-1) + \frac{\pi}{2} & -1\leq x< 0\\   \arcsin(2x-1) + \frac{\pi}{2} & 0\leq x\leq 1  \end{cases}$$